# didSelectRowAtIndexPath: only being invoked after ~3 second hold on cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am loading my cells from a nib, which are subclasses of `UITableViewCell`.

Each of these cells are setup with `userInteraction` set to `YES` (in the nib file).

When tapping on a cell, the selection of the cell isn't shown (in this case grey) unless the tap is held for a brief moment.

Even when the cell selection style is shown, lifting the finger off the cell still doesn't fire `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

As mentioned the only way to fire it is to hold down on the cell for about 3 seconds.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? All of the delegates are set up correctly, I also use the dequeuing method of loading cells.

Thanks for any advice and pointers!

***EDIT 2***

Apologies, misunderstood the deselect methods. Here they are working:

```
2012-12-28 04:20:28.120 myApp[2022:907] willSelectRowAtIndexPath: <NSIndexPath 0x1cda0400> 2 indexes [0, 0]
2012-12-28 04:20:28.130 myApp[2022:907] didSelectRowAtIndexPath: <NSIndexPath 0x1cda0400> 2 indexes [0, 0]

2012-12-28 04:20:32.166 myApp[2022:907] willSelectRowAtIndexPath: <NSIndexPath 0x1d936630> 2 indexes [1, 0]
2012-12-28 04:20:32.168 myApp[2022:907] willDeselectRowAtIndexPath: <NSIndexPath 0x1cd24770> 2 indexes [0, 0]
2012-12-28 04:20:32.171 myApp[2022:907] didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: <NSIndexPath 0x1cd24770> 2 indexes [0, 0]
2012-12-28 04:20:32.178 myApp[2022:907] didSelectRowAtIndexPath: <NSIndexPath 0x1d936630> 2 indexes [1, 0]
```

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellID"];

    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSArray *data = [[self.indexedData objectForKey:kIndexedDataKey] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CustomObject *dataObject = [data objectAtIndex:0];

    [cell setDataObject:dataObject];

    return cell;
}
```

Custom cell properties:

[image]

All of the subviews (of the cell) have the same properties:

[image]

Comment: Can you NSLog `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, `tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`, and `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`, and tell us what the time difference is between each?

Comment: Okay, how about the time difference between `willSelect` and `didSelect`?

Comment: *updated log in question

Comment: Is this log all from one press on a single cell?

Comment: In each log, the index path of the affected cell is logged too

Comment: You need to post your code -- we can't help without it.

Comment: Theres no code I could really post which would help is there?

Comment: How about what you have in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, I think that would be helpful. Also, information about your table view cell.

Comment: My guess based on symptoms would be that you are using a gesture recognizer, either attached to the cell or the tableview, that needs to fail before it will pass on touches to the tableview/cell.

Comment: Your exactly right! I fell like an idiot, at the beginning of development i added a tap recognizer on the `UITableView` before I added cells to test some functionality. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AdamCarter. Don't worry, we all have our "fail" moments. Mine was yesterday, now it's your turn. ;-)

Comment: @AceLegend you're right, just hope it doesnt happen again too soon!!

Answer (score 3):

As stupid as I feel, as @NJones said, I had a `UITapGestureRecognizer` attached to the `UITableView`. When I remove this, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is a bit old, but I was faced with the same issue:

For me, the problem was because my `UITableView` was added to an `UIScrollView` and more specifically to its `contentView`.
It appears that inside the `contentView`, I had to stay press 2-3 sec to fire the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

I moved my TableView to `self.view` instead of `contentView` and it solved the problem!